# What's the fastest way to catch wild Pokémon?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

I'm wondering if there's some sort of trick or strategy to catch wild Pokémon faster in this generation. It's ok if the technique doesn't work on legendaries.

Answer (score 1):

The best way I know and that I usually use is to take a Pokémon knowing the [Hold Back](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Hold_Back_(move)) or [False Swipe](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/False_Swipe_(move)) moves. Those techniques damage the opponents but make sure to leave with him at least 1 life point, even if you hit the opponent while he has one life point left.

Now, since this generation, wild Pokémon love to call for help when they are too weak. For this matter, my Pokémon who knows Hold Back or False Swipe also knows the [Yawn](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Yawn_(move)) move, which makes sure the opponent Pokémon fall asleep the following turn. Then the strategy is the following:

1. Use Yawn.
2. Use Hold Back or False Swipe. The opponent will fall asleep at the end of this turn.
3. If the opponent's life point are still not at 1, use Hold Back or False Swipe again. Else jump to 4.
4. Launch your ball (the one with the highest chance of catch depending on the context).

With an opponent asleep who can't call for help and with only 1 life point left, you maximize your chances to capture a wild Pokémon. This is of course assuming your Pokémon is strong enough to quickly put down the life points of the other Pokémon.

Comment: Using a Quick Ball plus Yawn also helps

Comment: Quick ball only works 1st turn with 5x catch...

Comment: I use the same strategy. It works well in most situations. If you're trying to catch a Geodude or similar, I recommend using Quick balls instead. Those things usually explode on the first or second turn.

Answer (score 1):

IMO the best way is to stock up on quick balls. When used on first turn, it's 5x catch rate, insta-catching most pokemon.

For legendaries though, better to false swipe/hold back them until they get low and throw a ball.

Comment: I caught all my legendaries in Quick Balls.